# What does 연화 mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I purchased the reword app and have found some odd translations. Particularly, 연화, which is being translated as "soft currency." Google translate translates it as softening, a google image search result shows some anime, and Wiktionary has no results.

Is this legit? Is it a trendy current word or like an out of date translation?

Comment: Where did you find 연화? 연화 can also mean a lotus flower or lotus flowers.

Comment: These are various meanings of this word with a quick google search: https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%97%B0%ED%99%94. What context are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

They are both legit, but 연화 "soft currency" is quite a rare term (unless you are an economist, I guess) - if you say 연화 without context, people will most likely assume "softening" or a personal name.

Even 연화 softening sounds like a technical term describing some kind of industrial process.  For everyday usage, people will use verbs like 무르다/물러지다/부드러워지다/etc.  If you are a beginner, you don't really need to learn 연화 right now.

연화 (軟貨, soft currency): [Naver dictionary](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/6892ea8d0e17480296c7d43d34a5e4d7), see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_currency) (English)

연화 (軟化, softening): [Naver dictionary](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/fd5438772bd4432d891010b5981cf16a)